# How to extract war file on target using ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I'm using unarchive module of Ansible and that doesn't seem to be working to extract the war file. It works fine for .tar.

There's also a switch `setype`: *"type part of SELinux file context"* that I'm not sure if can be used to set the type of file as war.

I tried this:

```
-name: Unpack war
 unarchive: src=~/wars/mywar.war
            dest=/tmp/deploy
            setype=war
            copy=no
```

it gives error: `msg: Failed to find handler to unarchive. Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed.`

When I don't use 'setype' I get exact same error again.

How can I extract war file using Ansible?

Comment: setype has nothing to do with it it is for "Security Enhanced Linux" not for a  file type.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to unarchive a .war file using Ansible.
Are you sure that 'unzip' is installed & the 'unzip' command available on your target system?

As per [Ansible Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html):
"requires gtar/unzip command on target host"

Comment: You can also run ansible with parameter `-vvv` to get a more verbose output - that usually tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ansible documentation for the [unarchive module](http://docs.ansible.com/unarchive_module.html) it only supports tar, gzip, bzip2, and xz compressed files. I quickly browsed through the source and didn't see any indication that it supports uncompressing war files. You will probably need to unpack the war file manually by invoking /path/to/java/bin/jar manually via the command or shell module.

Edit: Also, the setype parameter is not meant to specify the type of archive file. That parameter has to do with [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) (Security-Enhanced Linux).  If you're not familiar with SELinux then you likely don't need to be using that parameter at all.

Comment: also regular zip/unzip. But from what I read, war/jar files are essentially zips...

Comment: They are essentially zip files but they use the jar command to pack/unpack them rather than the unzip/untar/gunzip command.  The ansible module would need to be modified to support using the jar command when war files are specified in order to support unpacking them.

Comment: I proposed an earlier solution saying exactly this. It is wrong :) `ansible -i ../inventory/hosts local -m unarchive -a "src=zip-content.war dest=./extracted" -v` (war file created with `zip -r ...` from the command line) -- I can't comment on the actual error the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error myself with a ZIP archive - it failed because the ZIP was incomplete. Check that you can run `unzip ~/wars/mywar.war` directly on the server and you may get a more useful error message.